# reading sub-directories with bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a folder that contains couple hundred folders with images, inside each of thous folders are 4 images with random names, what I need to do is loop through all the subfolders, read the 4 image names of each sub-folder and run this command on them:

```
 convert \( $subdir/$file1.jpg $subdir/$file2.jpg -append \) \( $subdir/$file3.jpg $subdir/$file4.jpg -append \) +append $subdir.jpg
```

This is how it should work:

```
foreach(subdirectory in directory){
   $img_arr[] = new Array(); 
   foreach(file in subdirectory){
       $img_arr[] = file;
   }

   exec("convert \( $subdirectory /$img_arr[0].jpg $subdirectory /$img_arr[1].jpg -append \) \( $subdirectory/$img_arr[2].jpg $subdirectory/$img_arr[3].jpg -append \) +append $subdirectory.jpg");
}
```

This is what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

img=0;

IFS=$'\n'

for NAME in $(find -type f)
  do
   echo "Found a file: \"$NAME\""
done
```

I'm trying to combine 4 images into one using imagemagick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for dir in *
do
     test -d $dir || continue
     files=($dir/*.jpg)
     convert \( ${files[0]} ${files[1]} -append \) \( ${files[2]} ${files[3]} -append \) +append $dir.jpg
done
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! so this will not mix up images from different folders, correct?

Comment: Right, this only combines images that are in the same directory.

Comment: It runs `convert` once per directory, and all the arguments passed to `convert` are from that directory, so no, it won't mix up images from different folders.  Note, however, that the above script won't work if any of the filenames have spaces in them.

Comment: That's an important caveat I should have mentioned, thanks @MarkReed!

Answer (score 2):

Your initial approach was almost fine, just a few changes:

```
for dir in $(find . -type d); do
    echo $dir; 
done
```